# GWC Layers published with WMTS are displayed poorly at different locations

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I am using a Geoserver with in built Geowebcache and the WMTS extension to provide 2 kind of layers to a Mapbox frontend.

Features are dynamically updated to a PostGIS database.

It works quite well on some locations but very unprecise on others and I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong with the GWC configuration.

Could you please explain me the functionality behind the native/latlong BoundingBox of a layer? Do I have to update them via REST on Ingest a new feature? What about the Grid subset bounds in Layer Caching, can't those be configured to be dynamic?

Is there maybe an option I am missing to extend the cache on requests? Since I am also using cql_filter to filter the data on an attribute this would be quite helpful.

Comment: If your features are dynamic there is hardly any point in caching the tiles as they will keep changing.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I can only use WMTS with the gwc, right? Would you recommend using WFS instead because of the tile caching?
Does it make a difference that features are only added, never removed?

Comment: It makes no sense to use a tiled caching system if your data is dynamic, just use a simple WMS